# Do Bios interrupts always sits on ram?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, embedded, bios

My question is Do Bios interrupts sit in RAM even after operating system loaded? If yes then that part of ram which keeps bios interrupts and interrupt handlers is reserved and not overridden by other programs. Is that right?
 Thanks in Advance

Comment: Technically the BIOS is not in RAM, but ROM. At bootup it's normal to copy it to RAM for performance, though. Either way, the typical address range for the motherboard BIOS is `0xF0000` to `0xFFFFF`, with VGA BIOS at `0xC0000` to `0xC7FFF`. You normally have access to 640k RAM up to `0xA0000` (somewhat less) in real mode. See also [wiki.osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29).

Comment: If you boot a protected mode OS, that will reassign memory ranges as it sees fit, and does not use BIOS interrupts (but may use BIOS/ROM data).

Comment: Let's say i want to use BIOS interrupts in my program does it go and retrieve it from ROM or it just retrieve it from RAM. If it fetches from RAM then in that particular address range is reserved for BIOS and it never overridden after operating system loaded. Is that Right?

Comment: traditionally each card could have a rom if it wanted which contained a bios for that card, and that bios would be used for those interrupts.  but soft bioses came along not long after so you could have handlers in ram or rom.  does it matter?   the vector table can be modified so that makes what kind of storage the handler in irrelevant right?  just have to protect the vector table from bad software

Comment: the operating system may very well take over bios calls for good reason, have the handler be os friendly rather than a back door around the os that can do damage

Comment: for a virtual machine you want all of the bios calls trapped by the virtual machine, which basically means they are all in ram and interface to the operating system or the virtual machine

Comment: In typical protected mode operating systems you can not use BIOS interrupts, and you do not have access to physical memory anyway. So the whole question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Because RAM is volatile and is completely erased when the power is turned off, the code that handles the BIOS interrupts doesn't exist in RAM. It's all in ROM (or actually flash memory these days). There is however one critical part of how interrupts are handled that's kept in RAM and that's the Interrupt Vector Table (IVT), which stores the address of all the interrupt routines. The CPU uses this table to find the address of the code to execute in order to handle interrupts. The BIOS interrupt routines also use RAM store various bits of data they need to function.

When an modern protected-mode operating starts it has to completely replace all interrupt routines with its own. It has to do this because the BIOS's interrupt  code won't work in protected mode. Unless the OS takes special steps to preserve the old IVT in RAM that the BIOS created, along with any data the BIOS stored in RAM, then this information is lost. That means it's no longer possible to use BIOS interrupts without rebooting the machine. The RAM used by the BIOS to handle interrupts is not reserved an the OS can use it how it pleases.

The only protected-mode operating systems that I know that preserve the BIOS's IVT and data are Windows 95, 98 and ME. These are also the only operating systems that would let you invoke a BIOS interrupt from a user-mode program, and then only reliably from a 16-bit application.